# swift 3 facebook integration

Tags: swift, facebook, xcode8

trying to get Facebook connect working from a swift project.

Have been trying to follow along the following youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6rTmfLp9aY

which unfortunately for me is in German.

so this is what I have so far:

1. I have my Facebook app with IOS enabled enabled and I planted my bundleID there.
2. Downloaded latest iOS framework and added to project

to the AppDelegate file I added:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()
    return true
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

and this is the ViewController file

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit




class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

              if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil)
        {
            let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
            content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "{Facebook link to app}") as URL!
            FBSDKAppInviteDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: self)
        }
        else
        {
            let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            self.view.addSubview(loginView)
            loginView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY + 100)
            loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




func appInviteDialog (_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!)
{

}


func appInviteDialog (_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didFailWithError  error: Error!) {
    print("Error took place in appInviteDialog \(error)")
}


func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        //process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        //handle cancelation
    }
    else {

        let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
        content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "{Facebook link to app}") as URL!
        FBSDKAppInviteDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: self)

        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            //do work
        }
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

}


}
```

No errors and no alerts. When i run simulator I get an empty screen. Must be doing something right cause I get the following msg:

SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-06-04 00:42:02.351876+0300 facebook_login[4569:144075] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.

also, if I just paste in viewDidLoad the following lines from the code:

```
            let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            self.view.addSubview(loginView)
            loginView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY + 100)
            loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
```

I get a beautiful Facebook button in simulator that of course crashes when i press it.

any help to  work will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has a Swift SDK you might find easier to use than the Objective-C one (which they just call iOS). Try looking around the documentation here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift

Also, follow the steps described in the (other) iOS SDK to get started:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

This is the minimal app delegate I could get to work (notice the Swift SDK is missing the FB prefixes that exist in the iOS SDK):

```
import UIKit
import FacebookCore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }

}
```

And be sure to add all the required keys in your `Info.plist` or else you won't get authentication to work at all.

Comment: I understood that Facebook swift sdk does not support current swift and Xcode

Comment: I'm using with the latest versions of Xcode and Swift with just a couple of minor warnings building the framework. Anyway, they're not that different and I'm pretty sure you can accomplish the same things with both of them, if you prefer the other SDK. Just make sure to follow all the steps in the documentation. Pay attention to the App Delegate and to `Info.plist`.

Comment: code works now. I forgot to update Info.plist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith 
 result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

if ((error) != nil) {
    // Process error
    print("Error! : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return

} else if result.isCancelled {
    // Handle cancellations
    print("Success! : user cancel login request")
    return
} else {
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, email, name,picture.type(large)"])
    graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            // Do work in app.
            let dataDict:NSDictionary = result as! NSDictionary
            if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString {
                print("tocken: \(token)")

                let userDefult = UserDefaults.standard
                userDefult.setValue(token, forKey: "access_tocken")
                userDefult.synchronize()
            }
            if let user : NSString = dataDict.object(forKey: "name") as! NSString? {
                print("user: \(user)")
            }
            if let id : NSString = dataDict.object(forKey: "id") as? NSString {
                print("id: \(id)")
            }
            if let email : NSString = (result! as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email") as? NSString {
                print("email: \(email)")
            }

                                if let pictureData:NSDictionary = dataDict.object(forKey: "picture") as? NSDictionary{

                                    if let data:NSDictionary = pictureData.object(forKey: "data") as? NSDictionary{

                                        if let strPictureURL: String = data.object(forKey: "url") as? String{

                                            self.imageviewUser.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: strPictureURL)! as URL)! as Data)
                           }
                        }
                    }
               }
          })
      }

   }

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) 
 {
 FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrent(nil)
 FBSDKProfile.setCurrent(nil)
 let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()
 manager.logOut()
```

}

Comment: Facebook Integration swift - They are two delegate method used for login and logout